# value of parameter from object on flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and I am trying to get an object from a list of objects and I have used the following.

```
setProject (int idProject) {
var selectedProject =
this._projectsUser.where ((project) => project ['id'] == idProject);
// print ('selectedProject $ {selectedProject}');
this._project = selectedProject;
}
```

where the variables are:

```
List _projectsUser = [];
Object _project = {};
```

but when I want to get a value of an object parameter I get the following error: `The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.`

Comment: Your **_projectUser** is empty, did you call the method with the empty list?

Comment: no it's a full list

Comment: Where exactly is the error coming from? I ran your code and it worked fine

Comment: this._projectsUser is a List (36 items) and i need get only one with 'Where" but i get a WhereIterrable type and i cant get a parameter

Comment: So you are getting the first project that meets that condition as a map?

Answer (score 0):

Test this

```
 setProject (int idProject) {
    var selectedProject = this._projectsUser.where ((project) => project ['id'] == idProject).toList()[0];
    this._project = selectedProject;
    print(selectedProject);
  }

  List _projectsUser = [{'id':1, 'name':'nothing'},{'id':1, 'name':'nothing2'},{'id':1, 'name':'nothing2'}];
  Object _project = {};
```

Comment: I just kept random data in the list, It can be ignored

Comment: Worked for you?